# Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline remove Quotes and double Backslashes from passed Variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Pipeline that expect a Ansible-Playbook as passed variable on queue-time (`string`). After converting my classic Pipeline to YAML I recognize that **Quotes** in the Playbook-String are missing.

#### Classic Pipeline passed Playbook (`"`)

```
---
  - 
    hosts: "all"
    gather_facts: true
    vars: 
      SoftwareFolder: "ansibleshare"
      SoftwareSource: "/mnt/{{ SoftwareFolder }}"
      AnsibleRoot: "D:/Ansible"
      Proxy: "http://www-cache.de:3128"
    tasks: 
      - 
        name: "set windows proxy settings"
        win_inet_proxy: 
          auto_detect: false
          proxy: "{{ Proxy }}"
...
```

#### YAML Pipeline passed Playbook (`"`)

```
---
  - 
    hosts: all
    gather_facts: true
    vars: 
      SoftwareFolder: ansibleshare
      SoftwareSource: /mnt/{{ SoftwareFolder }}
      AnsibleRoot: D:/Ansible
      Proxy: http://www-cache.de:3128
    tasks: 
      - 
        name: set windows proxy settings
        win_inet_proxy: 
          auto_detect: false
          proxy: {{ Proxy }}
...
```

---

I try to wrap the Playbook in single Quotes, before passing it (`'${yaml}'`), but that dosn't help.

Quotes are an essential component of Playbooks, I'm pretty sure there are reasons, why the pipeline behave like that. But as a stakeholder, it is feel bad when a variable get changed by passing it and also, in classic Pipelines was no need to do that.

**How can I solve it?**

---

#### Meta:

```
18.170.30525.1 (Azure DevOps Server 2020)
on prem
API: "azure-devops-node-api": "^10.2.1"
```

---

### EDIT 1

Another problem in context of ansible-playbooks is the fact that YAML pipelines also misinterpreting double backslashes `\\`, which are very important for windows paths in playbooks:

#### Classic Pipeline passed Playbook (`\\`)

```
      - 
        name: "msi install 7z"
        win_package: 
          path: "{{ AnsibleRoot }}\\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\\7z\\7z.msi"
          state: "present"
      - 
        name: "exe install git client"
        win_package: 
          path: "{{ AnsibleRoot }}\\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\\git\\Git.exe"
          state: "present"
          product_id: "git"
          creates_path: "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe"
          arguments: 
            - "/SILENT"
```

#### YAML Pipeline passed Playbook (`\\`)

```
      - 
        name: msi install 7z
        win_package: 
          path: {{ AnsibleRoot }}\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\7z\7z.msi
          state: present

      - 
        name: exe install git client
        win_package: 
          path: {{ AnsibleRoot }}\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\git\Git.exe
          state: present
          product_id: git
          creates_path: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
          arguments: 
            - /SILENT
```

This makes YAML-Pipelines really hard to use for that use case. :(

---

### EDIT 2

#### YAML Pipeline Content

```
# NAME
name: "$(Build.BuildId)-$(Build.SourceBranchName) ($(Build.RequestedFor))"

# TRIGGER
trigger: none

# VARIABLES
variables:
  - name: "PathPlaybook"
    value: "ansible-playbook.yml"
  - name: "PathInventory"
    value: "ansible-inventory.yml"

# STAGES
stages:
  # ----------------------------------------------------------- BUILD
  - stage: "Build"

    # POOL
    pool:
      name: "Ansible"
    
    # JOBS
    jobs:
      - job:
        displayName: "Agent job"

        # STEPS
        steps:

          # BASH SCRIPT TO CREATE FILE FROM PASSED PARAMETER TO TARGET MACHINE
          - task: Bash@3
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                echo '$(Inventory)' > $(PathInventory)
                echo '$(Playbook)' > $(PathPlaybook)
                
                echo Inventory:
                echo '$(Inventory)'
                
                echo Playbook:
                echo '$(Playbook)'
          
          # ANSIBLE
          - task: Ansible@0
            displayName: Ansible Agent'
            inputs:
              playbookPathOnAgentMachine: '$(PathPlaybook)'
              inventoriesAgentMachine: file
              inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: '$(PathInventory)'
              failOnStdErr: false
```

#### Description

- Pipeline receive `Inventory` and `Playbook` as `string`
- Bash Task write `string` into file and produce the output I publish above (more for debug reasons)
- Ansible execute the files

Please keep in mind. Same Pipeline in classic runs well:

[image]

---

### EDIT 3: parameter for queueBuild function

I use 3 parameter for the `queueBuild` function

- ``buildOption = see below
- projectName = `MyProject`
- ignoreWarnings = `true`

#### buildOption as Object

```
definition:{id: 23}
parameters:'{"Inventory":"---\n  all: \n    hosts: \n      PTC-BLD-ADA5: \n        ansible_user: \"PTC-SVC-ADS-AGT\"\n        ansible_password: \"AgentPW2019\"\n        ansible_port: 5986\n        ansible_connection: \"winrm\"\n        ansible_winrm_transport: \"ntlm\"\n        ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: \"ignore\"\n","Playbook":"---\n  - \n    hosts: \"all\"\n    gather_facts: true\n    vars: \n      SoftwareFolder: \"ansibleshare\"\n      SoftwareSource: \"/mnt/{{ SoftwareFolder }}\"\n      AnsibleRoot: \"D:\\\\Ansible\"\n      Proxy: \"http://www-cache.psitrans.de:3128\"\n    tasks: \n      - \n        name: \"set windows proxy settings\"\n        win_inet_proxy: \n          auto_detect: false\n          proxy: \"{{ Proxy }}\"\n      - \n        name: \"create directory ansible\"\n        win_file: \n          path: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\"\n          state: \"directory\"\n      - \n        name: \"copy software to target machine\"\n        win_copy: \n          src: \"{{ SoftwareSource }}\"\n          dest: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\"\n      - \n        name: \"exe install git client\"\n        win_package: \n          path: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\\\\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\\\\git\\\\Git.exe\"\n          state: \"present\"\n          product_id: \"git\"\n          creates_path: \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Git\\\\cmd\\\\git.exe\"\n          arguments: \n            - \"/SILENT\"\n      - \n        name: \"msi install 7z\"\n        win_package: \n          path: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\\\\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\\\\7z\\\\7z.msi\"\n          state: \"present\"\n"}'
sourceBranch:'refs/heads/master'
```

#### buildOption as JSON

```
{
  "definition": { "id": 23 },
  "id": 23,
  "parameters": "{\"Inventory\":\"---\n  all: \n    hosts: \n      PTC-BLD-ADA5: \n        ansible_user: \"PTC-SVC-ADS-AGT\"\n        ansible_password: \"AgentPW2019\"\n        ansible_port: 5986\n        ansible_connection: \"winrm\"\n        ansible_winrm_transport: \"ntlm\"\n        ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: \"ignore\"\n\",\"Playbook\":\"---\n  - \n    hosts: \"all\"\n    gather_facts: true\n    vars: \n      SoftwareFolder: \"ansibleshare\"\n      SoftwareSource: \"/mnt/{{ SoftwareFolder }}\"\n      AnsibleRoot: \"D:\\\\Ansible\"\n      Proxy: \"http://www-cache.psitrans.de:3128\"\n    tasks: \n      - \n        name: \"set windows proxy settings\"\n        win_inet_proxy: \n          auto_detect: false\n          proxy: \"{{ Proxy }}\"\n      - \n        name: \"create directory ansible\"\n        win_file: \n          path: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\"\n          state: \"directory\"\n      - \n        name: \"copy software to target machine\"\n        win_copy: \n          src: \"{{ SoftwareSource }}\"\n          dest: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\"\n      - \n        name: \"exe install git client\"\n        win_package: \n          path: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\\\\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\\\\git\\\\Git.exe\"\n          state: \"present\"\n          product_id: \"git\"\n          creates_path: \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Git\\\\cmd\\\\git.exe\"\n          arguments: \n            - \"/SILENT\"\n      - \n        name: \"msi install 7z\"\n        win_package: \n          path: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\\\\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\\\\7z\\\\7z.msi\"\n          state: \"present\"\n\"}",
  "sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master"
}
```

My application call the `queueBuild` function with the `buildOption` as Object, like expected.

Important is to know that that works totally fine for *classic Pipelines*, only *YAML Pipelines* make changes for the passed parameter descripted like above.

Comment: Can you show the relevant portions of your YAML pipeline that experience this problem?

Comment: How did you pass the playbook string as variable. What tasks you are using in your pipeline?

Comment: I extend my question with the pipeline content. The pipeline get queued with the `azure-devops-node-api": "^10.2.1"` api. `Inventory` and `Playbook` get passed via `queueBuild` function as `BuildInterfaces.Build`. Click [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/blob/470f9ca7bdfccd87e1c1fdea8023b8c3d2b1047a/api/BuildApi.ts#L37) for more information.

Comment: Could you share the parameters string you passed in BuildInterfaces.Build? I can successfully pass the string to yaml pipeline with `"` and " \\" keeped. The " and "\\ "must be escaped like this `path: \\"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\\\\\\\\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\\\\\\\\git\\\\\\\\Git.exe\\" ` in the parameters string  in BuildInterfaces.Build

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I add the full passed parameter to my question. Is there a general `regex` to create a escaped pipeline parameter string to get correct interpreted by a **YAML Pipeline**?

Comment: can you please help with my question? thank you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67850656/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-change-quotes-to-backslashes-and-double-quotes-from-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can successfully passed the parameter string with " and " \" keeped using `String.raw` method. See below:

```
let ps = String.raw `{"Inventory":"---\n  all: \n    hosts: \n      PTC-BLD-ADA5: \n        ansible_user: \"PTC-SVC-ADS-AGT\"\n        ansible_password: \"AgentPW2019\"\n        ansible_port: 5986\n        ansible_connection: \"winrm\"\n        ansible_winrm_transport: \"ntlm\"\n        ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: \"ignore\"\n","Playbook":"---\n  - \n    hosts: \"all\"\n    gather_facts: true\n    vars: \n      SoftwareFolder: \"ansibleshare\"\n      SoftwareSource: \"/mnt/{{ SoftwareFolder }}\"\n      AnsibleRoot: \"D:\\\\Ansible\"\n      Proxy: \"http://www-cache.psitrans.de:3128\"\n    tasks: \n      - \n        name: \"set windows proxy settings\"\n        win_inet_proxy: \n          auto_detect: false\n          proxy: \"{{ Proxy }}\"\n      - \n        name: \"create directory ansible\"\n        win_file: \n          path: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\"\n          state: \"directory\"\n      - \n        name: \"copy software to target machine\"\n        win_copy: \n          src: \"{{ SoftwareSource }}\"\n          dest: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\"\n      - \n        name: \"exe install git client\"\n        win_package: \n          path: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\\\\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\\\\git\\\\Git.exe\"\n          state: \"present\"\n          product_id: \"git\"\n          creates_path: \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Git\\\\cmd\\\\git.exe\"\n          arguments: \n            - \"/SILENT\"\n      - \n        name: \"msi install 7z\"\n        win_package: \n          path: \"{{ AnsibleRoot }}\\\\{{ SoftwareFolder }}\\\\7z\\\\7z.msi\"\n          state: \"present\"\n"}`; 
        
let vstsdef : bi.Build = {
        definition: { id: 48 },
        parameters: ps
       };
    
let nq = await build.queueBuild(vstsdef,"TestProject")
```

See below output from yaml pipeline:

[image]