# Azure DevOps API - Push a YAML file from a powershell script

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-devops-rest-api

> Objective : Push a YAML file from a powershell script using the Azure DevOps API.

According to the Azure DevOps documentation I was able to get this following code :

```
$pushFileJSON = @{
    refUpdates = @(
        @{
            name = $branchToPush
            oldObjectId = $oldObjectId
        }
    )
    commits = @(
        @{
            comment = "Added azure-pipelines.yml file."
            changes = @(
                @{
                    changeType = "add"
                    item = @{
                        path = "/azure-pipelines.yml"
                    }
                    newContent = @{
                        content = $yamlContent
                        contentType = "rawtext"
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
$request = 'https://dev.azure.com/' + $organization + '/' + $projectName + '/_apis/git/repositories/' + $repositoriesId + '/pushes?api-version=6.0'
$responsePushYAML = Invoke-RestMethod $request -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $pushFileJSON -ContentType "application/json"
```

But due to the JSON field `newContent` and so `content` who is a string field if, as I do currently, give  the YAML content this last one when he is pushed on the branch I got a file like this :

```
# Starter pipeline # Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code. # Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more: # https://aka.ms/yaml  variables:   - group: 'AutoMergeTestBranch'   # Agent & Container parameter   - name:  'AgentPool'     value: 'DemoAgent' jobs: - job: Start_Build_Agent   displayName: "Start Build Agent"   workspace:     clean: all   pool: 'Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019'   steps:     - task: PowerShell@2
```

Without any indentation or correct syntax :/ Does anyone know hot to push a YAML file to a repo ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the Git client, such that you'd clone the repo, add the YAML file, commit and push the change via Git?

Answer (score 1):

> Without any indentation or correct syntax

Check this sample: [Update a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#update-a-file), it add the field `\n` to wrap, we also need add `\n` and   to change the indentation and syntax.

$yamlContent:

```
# Starter pipeline\n# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.\n# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more: # https://aka.ms/yaml\nvariables:\n- group: 'AutoMergeTestBranch'\n# Agent & Container parameter\n- name:  'AgentPool'\n  value: 'DemoAgent'\njobs:\n  - job: Start_Build_Agent\n    displayName: Start Build Agent\n    workspace:\n      clean: all\n    pool: 'Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019'\n    steps:\n    - task: PowerShell@2
```

Result:

[image]

You could also check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558645/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-remove-quotes-and-double-backslashes-from-passed-vari/66652574).

Comment: Hi Vito, I've tried your solution but unfortunately this doesn't work for me. In fact, I get the same result as before a one line file. Could you please share your powershell script solution which allows you to get the correct yaml file above ?